# example from you don't know JS

Tags: javascript

I copied the code from YDKJS(https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md)

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.bar );
}

var bar = "global";

var obj1 = {
    bar: "obj1",
    foo: foo
};

var obj2 = {
    bar: "obj2"
};

// --------

foo();              // "global"
obj1.foo();         // "obj1"
foo.call( obj2 );       // "obj2"
new foo();          // undefined
```

explained here that:
foo() ends up setting this to the global object in non-strict mode -- in strict mode, this would be undefined and you'd get an error in accessing the bar property -- so "global" is the value found for this.bar.

why in strict mode, foo(); will be undefined?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Comment: I think it's a matter of defining `var bar = "global"` Variables should not be globally defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `boxing` in JS. The value passed as `this` to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object. JS changes the `this` object when entering the context of the foo() function. In your sample code you are not calling the function as a part of an object, so its value will be undefined. If you do not use strict mode, the value of `this` is automatically set to the window object.
more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode